# JAVA Derby, problems viewing the data entered in the table

Tags: sql, jdbc, derby

Good night guys!

I created a connection to the Derby in java , I insert data in the table , but when I run the code to display the data in the table with System.out.printl , Java gives me a message connection Ok ! but nothing to show me the data on the console , I'm using the clause SELECT * FROM ... I'll post the code , and if they have some more example code, or choose to send another code will be well accepted , look my code :

```
package tests ;
import java.sql . * ;

 public class AcessoBanco {

    public static void main ( String [ ] args ) {

    
        Connection con = null;

    try {

      con = DriverManager.getConnection ( " jdbc : derby : database " , " Ramom " , " banco123 " ) ;

      Statement sta = con.createStatement ( ) ;


// Getting the data back


      ResultSet res = sta.executeQuery ( " SELECT * FROM APP.TablePTBR " ) ;
 

      while ( res.next ()) {




// THIS LINE(SYSTEM.OUT...) DOES NOT SEEM TO BE WORKING, PLEASE take a look ! 

         System.out.println ( res.getInt ("code") + " , " + res.getString ( "user " ) ) ;

         
      }

      res.close ();


      sta.close ();


      con.close ();


    } Catch ( Exception e ) {






      System.err.println ( " Exception : " + e.getMessage ( ) ) ;


    }


  }


}
```

My problem is not connecting, but the problem is SELECT and view table data in JAVA console with System.out.println and when I run the command "Insert Into ..." java does not show me any connection error and no error insertion, when I check in the GUI in Derby table, there is no data there..
Thank you guys!

Comment: I think you shouldn't use * in your query, instead, use names of the columns and see if any results are printed to the output.

Comment: I don't get it by this is going well but I do not connect?

Comment: Sorry bro I'm Brazilian, my english is bad ! I Try to repair the write erros. See my question now   :)

Comment: How did you insert the data in the table? By any chance, did you fail to COMMIT the insert transaction, and it was backed out?

Comment: Explain to me with more details and examples my friend did not understand.